# How to save to Firebase under existing child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

below is my Requests table which contain 'drinks' and '0' (0 equal to quantity of drink). However, I need to save some more data under 'drink'>'0'>**'topping'**.

Do you guys have any ides on how do I save data into 'topping' using database.getReference("topping");

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the child after getReference()

```
 database.getReference.child(1511377584775).child(drink).child("topping");
```

Comment: Thanks :) What if "Request" is created from for example, 1.java and "topping" will be created in 2.java which is a different java class. How can i access the table "Request"? Or do i need to ask another question for this? Thanks for your support and help